# Find tags containing characters that aren't [a-z] or [0-9]

Tags: sql, t-sql, dataexplorer

I want to create a query for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer which returns any tag containing special characters. (Specifically, any character that is not `a-z`, `0-9`, `-`, or `+`)

The search should return tags like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [c#-to-f#](/questions/tagged/c%23-to-f%23), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), and [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7).

I've tried a few different solutions, but each seems to have it's own set of issues.

---

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
```

**Source**: [*Oracle SQL - REGEXP_LIKE contains characters other than a-z or A-Z*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9604751/3357935)

**Error**: `REGEXP_LIKE` is not a recognized built-in function name.

---

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname NOT REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
```

**Source**: *[How to get all rows that contain characters others than [a-zA-Z] in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150493/3357935)*

**Error**: Incorrect syntax near `REGEXP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to phrase "contains only non-special characters" in SQL and negating that, it's easier to phrase "contains a special character":

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname LIKE '%[^-+a-z0-9]%'
```

You'll find that this contains a *lot* of tags containing `.`. You may wish to add this to the characters to ignore as well.

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tagname LIKE '%[^-+a-z0-9.]%'
```